# Creating polygon shapes in numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, polygon, shapes

I would like to create a numpy array of all zeros but insert 1's to create a rectangle or other polygon shape.

As a simplified example, I'd like to generate an array that looks like:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but I'd like to be able to create arbitrary rectangle outlines with zeros inside/outside the rectangle.  Additionally, I would like to be able to rotate the rectangle within the zeros backdrop.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Scikit-image has a draw polygon method https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html?highlight=draw#skimage.draw.polygon

Comment: Thank you.  I've never used scikit before but this looks like a good tool to get me started.